# define dynamic array inside a struct without causing a segmentation fault

Tags: struct, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

I'm new to c++ and I have to work with dynamic arrays:| I need to define a few dynamic arrays inside my header file and access them from main. The problem is that when I'm defining the arrays inside the structs, I get segmentation faults and don't know how to fix them.
Below is my header file.
I'm aware that there are lots of problems with my code and I could use your help. I'm really stuck here.
Thanks in advance.
I expect this code to work fine with dynamic arrays just like it does with vectors. But it's not.

`

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream> 
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

#define children_link_Size 149
#define row 15
#define col 100

using namespace std;


int itemListIndex = 0;
int freqIdx = 0;
int childIdx = 0;
int linkIdx = 0;

namespace std {
    template <typename T> T* begin(std::pair<T*, T*> const& p)
    {
        return p.first;
    }
    template <typename T> T* end(std::pair<T*, T*> const& p)
    {
        return p.second;
    }
}

struct Node
{
    int itemValue{};

    int order{ 0 };
    int freq{ 0 };
    Node* parent{ nullptr };
    Node* children{};
    Node* links{};

    Node() {
        children = new Node[children_link_Size];
        links = new Node[children_link_Size];
    }

    explicit Node(int const& p_value, int p_order = 0) :itemValue(p_value), order(p_order)
    {
        ++freq;
        cout << " + " << itemValue << " (" << order << ")" << endl;
    }

    bool operator ==(Node const& p_node) const
    {
        return itemValue == p_node.itemValue;
    }

    ~Node() {
        delete[] children;
        delete[] links;
    }
};


/*struct mySet {
    Node* OrderedItems;
    mySet()
    {
        OrderedItems = new Node[uniqueSize];
    }

    void insert(Node item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (item == OrderedItems[j])
                {
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    OrderedItems[i] = item;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    ~mySet()
    {
        delete[] OrderedItems;
    }
};*/


struct ItemSupport
{
    explicit ItemSupport(int p_minSup) { ItemSupport::minSup = p_minSup; }

    Node* Itemset = new (nothrow) Node[row];
    Node* OrderedItems = new (nothrow) Node[row];

    ItemSupport& operator<<(int const& p_itemValue)
    {
        static int order = 0;
        auto inode = find_if(Itemset, Itemset + row, [&p_itemValue](Node const& p_node)
        {
            return p_node.itemValue == p_itemValue;
        });

        if (inode == Itemset + row)
        {
            Node node(p_itemValue, order);
            Itemset[itemListIndex] = node;
            itemListIndex++;
            ++order;
        }
        else
        {
            auto& node = (*inode);
            ++node.freq;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& p_os, ItemSupport const& p_itemSupport)
    {
        ItemSupport* NoDe = {0};
        if (NoDe)
        {
            NoDe->OrderedItems = p_itemSupport.getFrequentItems();

            for (Node node : std::make_pair(NoDe->OrderedItems, NoDe->OrderedItems + row))
            {
                p_os << node.itemValue << ": support " << node.freq << ", order " << node.order << endl;
            }
            return p_os;
        }
    }

    Node* getItem(int const& p_itemValue)
    {
        auto inode = find_if(Itemset, Itemset + row, [&p_itemValue](Node const& p_node)
            {
                return p_node.itemValue == p_itemValue;
            });
        if (inode != Itemset + row)
        {
            Node* node = const_cast<Node*>(&(*inode));
            return node;
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    static int getMinSup()
    {
        return minSup;
    }

    static int minSup;

private:

    Node* getFrequentItems() const
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            if (Itemset[i].freq >= minSup)
                OrderedItems[j++] = Itemset[i];
        }
        return OrderedItems;
    }

    Node* getUnfrequentItems() const
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            if (Itemset[i].freq <= minSup)
                OrderedItems[j++] = Itemset[i];
        }
        return OrderedItems;
    }

    /*~ItemSupport() {
        //delete[] Itemset;
        //delete[] OrderedItems;
    }*/
};


int ItemSupport::minSup = 0;

struct FP_Tree
{
    explicit FP_Tree(ItemSupport& p_itemSupport, const int& p_rootValue = int()) :_headItemSupport(p_itemSupport)
    {
        _root = new Node(p_rootValue);
    }
    
    //void construct(Transaction const& p_itemValues)
    void construct(int *p_itemValues)
    {
        // A. Order items into transaction
        ItemSupport* ordered = {0};
        for (int const& itemValue : std::make_pair(p_itemValues, p_itemValues + row))
        {
            Node* pNode = _headItemSupport.getItem(itemValue);
            if (pNode && pNode->freq >= ItemSupport::getMinSup())
            {
                if (ordered)
                {
                    ordered->OrderedItems[freqIdx] = *pNode;
                    freqIdx++;
                }
            }
        }


        // B. Create FP_TREE
        Node* actualNode = _root;
        bool here = true;
        string tab;

        if (ordered)
        {
            for (Node const& node : std::make_pair(ordered->OrderedItems, ordered->OrderedItems + row))
            {
                tab += "\t-";
                auto it = actualNode->children;
                if (here)
                {
                    auto it = find_if(actualNode->children,
                        actualNode->children + children_link_Size,
                        [&node](Node const& nodeTmp) {
                            return node == (nodeTmp);
                        });
                    here &= it != actualNode->children + children_link_Size;
                }

                if (here)
                {
                    actualNode = it;
                    ++actualNode->freq;
                }
                else
                {
                    Node* pNode = new Node(node.itemValue);
                    actualNode->children[childIdx++] = *pNode;
                    pNode->parent = actualNode;
                    Node* pNodeHead = _headItemSupport.getItem(node.itemValue);
                    pNodeHead->links[linkIdx++] = *pNode;
                    actualNode = pNode;
                    delete pNode;
                }
                //cout  << tab << actualNode->_itemValue << "(" << actualNode->_freq << ")" << endl;
            }
        }
        //cout << endl;
    }



    ItemSupport& headItemSupport() const
    {
        return _headItemSupport;
    }

public:
    Node* root() const
    {
        return _root;
    }

private:
    ItemSupport& _headItemSupport;
    Node* _root;

};
```

`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

> I expect this code to work fine with dynamic arrays just like it does with vectors

Since you are using `C++`, *do* use `std::vector` -- it will save you a lot of trouble and there is *no reason* not to.